# How do I decrypt a text encrypted with SHA1 +MD5 combination without using any code? Is there any tools or sites available for this?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, md5, sha1

I got a text which is encrypted with sha1 and md5. What is the easiest way to decrypt it without coding. Is there any free tools or websites available for the same.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Password cracking? there are tons of sites that implemented rainbow tables, etc..

Answer (score 0):

you can't decrypt, that's the point.